# Github actions building a multi-platform image using multiple Dockerfiles

Tags: docker, github-actions

I would like to use github actions to build a multiarch image as explained here https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/blob/master/docs/advanced/multi-platform.md

All examples I find, use the same Dockerfile for all architectures. However, the project I am working with contains a different Dockerfile for each architecture. Is there a way to create a multi-arch image with github actions by consuming the different Dockerfiles?

Answer (score 2):

You can abuse the strategy matrix?

```
name: docker-latest

on:
  push:
    branches: master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        docker_target: [ 'x86_64:linux/amd64', 'arm:linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm/v8']
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up QEMU
      uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
    - name: Login to DockerHub
      uses: docker/login-action@v1
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}
    - name: docker buildx ${{ matrix.docker_target }}
      run: |
        DOCKER_FILE=$(echo "${{ matrix.docker_target }}" | cut -f1 -d:)/Dockerfile
        DOCKER_IMAGE=myImageName:latest
        DOCKER_PLATFORM=$(echo "${{ matrix.docker_target }}" | cut -f2 -d:)
        docker buildx build . --no-cache --platform ${DOCKER_PLATFORM} -t "${DOCKER_IMAGE}" -f "${DOCKER_FILE}" --push
```

This will depend on the behaviour of docker buildx since I think the --push will overwrite that tag completely so in this instance you might only end up with the various *arm* architectures and not the *amd64* or vice versa.

The question really here is, why does the architecture require different Dockerfiles (since I presume it's the same actual application). Surely you can use the `TARGETARCH` and `TARGETPLATFORM` args inside your Dockerfile to "do the right thing".